# Auto insert newline on interface methods in Netbeans 10?

Tags: netbeans, ide

How can I set the auto-format feature (`Alt+Shift+F`) to insert a newline on interface methods in Netbeans 10? E.g.,

[image]

As you can see the new line only works in class definitions (`class Foo2`) but not in interfaces (`interface Foo1`).

Can't seem to find the right setting at `Options > Editor > Formatting > PHP > Blank Lines`

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to do exactly what you want, but it is possible to format the code to insert a blank line between `public function bar1();` and `public function bar2();` by setting **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting > PHP > Blank Lines > Before Function** to **1**, and **After Function** to **0**.

However, the (possibly unwelcome) side effect is that you will get a blank line before every function, so formatting your file with those settings results in this:

[image: phpSource]

I'm guessing that you don't want the formatting to insert blank lines on line 5 and line 13 in the screen shot above, but I don't see how to prevent that while also having a blank line on line 7.

FYI, here are all the settings specified for **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting > PHP > Blank Lines**:

[image: formatSettings]

Comment: Yes the blanks on line 5 and 13 is exactly my problem! Seems like there's no way around it. Although this issue doesn't happen when you have fields e.g., `private $foo;`

Comment: OK, in that case I see no solution - sorry! The only thing you could try is seeing what happens on the latest NetBeans release, [Apache NetBeans 10.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html), and if you have the same problem there then raise a [NetBeans bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-1953?filter=allopenissues) since what you want to do seems completely reasonable..

Comment: I'm on the latest v10. Yeah I might just raise this with them. It's not critical just a minor annoyance. Thanks anyway!